# Characterizing minimal generating sets of a finite abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $G = \mathbb{Z}/d_1 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/d_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb{Z}/d_n$ be a finite abelian group of rank $n$, where $1 < d_1 \mid d_2 \mid \cdots \mid d_n$ (i.e., the above is an invariant factor decomposition for $G$).

I was wondering if the following condition for identifying a generating set of $G$ is true.

Suppose $g_1,\ldots,g_n$ are elements of $G$ such that

1. The quotient $G/\langle g_i\rangle $ has rank $n-1$ for each $i$
2. The intersection $\langle g_i\rangle \cap \langle g_j\rangle = \{0\}$ for all pairs $i \neq j$

Does it follow that the elements $\{g_1,\ldots,g_n\}$ generate $G$?

Note: I use the word *rank* to denote the minimal number of generators of a finite abelian group.

**Addendum:** The criterion stated above is false.  For example, $g_1 = (1,1,0), g_2 = (1,0,0), g_3 = (0,1,0)$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/p)^{\oplus 3}$.  If you'll allow me a second question, what happens if we replace the condition 2. with the stronger 2.' below?

2.' For any subset $I \subset \{1,\ldots,n\}$, the cyclic subgroups $\langle g_i \rangle $ for $i \in I$ generate a direct sum.

If I understand correctly, the statement is then true for elementary abelian $p$-groups $(\mathbb{Z}/p)^{\oplus n}$.  Does it remain true for any rank $n$ abelian group $G$?

Comment: 1) The first paragraph is irrelevant for the question. 2) Have you considered some simple examples first?

Comment: Namely, you can consider the case $d_1 = \ldots = d_n = p$ prime, so $G$ is an $\Bbb F_p$-vector space...

Comment: I realize that the question as I formulated it at the moment is false, since we can take, for instance, $g_1 = (0,1,0), g_2 = (1,0,0), g_3 = (1,1,0)$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/p)^{\oplus 3}$.  However, I had intended a stronger condition for 2.  Let me create an addendum to the question with a stronger version of 2.